# Terminology in combinatorics

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, partitions

I met the following two combinatorial concepts during a study outside of combinatorics. I am wondering if there are common terminologies in combinatorics.

1. A finite graph $G$ has the following property:

> For any vertex $a$ and edge $\{b,c\}$ of $G$, there is an edge connecting them: there is at least one of $\{a,b\}$ or $\{a,c\}$ in $G$.

2. Let $P = \lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_k$ be an integer partition of $n$. Suppose that $P$ has the following property:

> If there are two index sets $I$ and $J$ such that $\sum_{i \in I}\lambda_i = \sum_{j \in J}\lambda_j$, then the restricted partitions $\{\lambda_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{\lambda_j\}_{j \in J}$ are same.

For instance, $5 \ge 3 \ge 2 \ge 2$ does not have the property because $2+3=5$, but $5 \ge 5 \ge 3 \ge 3$ has the property.

Are there common names for these two properties?

Comment: @SamHopkins: These two concepts are related two special cases of `modular' birational contractions of moduli space of stable pointed rational curves. The first one is related to toric case, and the second one is related to $S_n$-invariant case. This question is because of my ignorance on combinatorics - I would like to follow a common name in my paper, if there is any.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the use of "common". (I thought it meant "encompassing both of the properties" rather than "usual".)

Comment: Well the first property is characterised by a forbidden induced subgraph: $\overline{P}_3$. I do not know any usual name for this property, and neither does graphclasses: http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/AUTO_2078.html

Comment: The first property says that non-adjacency is a transitive relation (if we count each vertex as non-adjacent to itself). So if you need to invent a name, I'd suggest "co-transitive".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thus the complement graph is the disjoint union of clicques, thus our graph is a complete multipartite graph. Well without specifying for what $k$ is it $k$-partite, so it is still kind of strange.

Comment: @DanielSoltész: Oh, thank you. So the graphs I've found are all of them. AndreasBlass: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @DanielSoltész : How about making your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is only an answer to your first question.

The graphs with your property can be characterised by forbidding as induced subgraph $\overline{P}_3$. By Andreas Blass's comment, your property implies that the complement of the graph is a disjoint union of cliques. These graphs are called complete multipartite graphs.

Sometimes for this kind of question the site http://graphclasses.org/ can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The second property is almost exactly the concept of "distinct subset sums", about which there are many beautiful unanswered questions. See, eg, http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/sets_with_distinct_subset_sums
The only difference between what you ask and the classical case is that you allow for repeated values.